# Reducing a 3d array to 2d

Tags: r

Is there a more succinct, one-liner way to do the following?

```
x <- array(1:12, dim = c(3, 2, 2))

> x[1,,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    7
[2,]    4   10

> x[2,,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    8
[2,]    5   11

> x[3,,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    9
[2,]    6   12

# Reduce 3d array to 2d (Is there a more elegant way?)
y <- x
dim(y) <- c(nrow(y), 4)


> y
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just feed your original array to the array constructor again, and use `dim` to get the dimension you want to preserve:

```
y <- array(x, dim = c(dim(x)[1], 4))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

If you wanted a version that doesn't rely on hardcoding the number of columns:

```
y <- array(x, dim = c(dim(x)[1], dim(x)[2] * dim(x)[3]))
```